# Multiple IF's in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Lately i have been making this batch file and it is driving me nuts.

My Folder Structure is like C:\MainFolder\Dir\  and "Dir" contains many sub Folders and Files. 
Within these Sub Folders there are many files and sub Folders including 2 files "C.txt" and "D.txt"
My Task is to delete everything else in these sub folders and only keep these 2 files. But it is not working. 
Please Help.

My Code is :

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%M in ('dir /b "C:\MainFolder\Dir\"') DO (
For /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('dir /b "C:\MainFolder\Dir\%%M"') DO ( 
if "%%S"=="C.txt" ( 
echo Found C
) 
else if "%%S"=="D.txt" ( 
echo Found D
) 
else (
::Code to delete the file Or Directory
echo Deleted %%S
)

)
)
echo Deleted Unwanted Content
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here:

The `else` has to appear on the same line as the `(`:

```
if "%%S"=="C.txt" ( 
  echo Found C
) else if "%%S"=="D.txt" ( 
  echo Found D
) else (
  ::Code to delete the file Or Directory
  echo Deleted %%S
)
```

Do not use `::` for comments, it breaks in certain places. Use `rem` instead:

```
) else (
  REM Code to delete the file Or Directory
  echo Deleted %%S
)
```

And please indent your code. It makes reading it much more pleasant:

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%M in ('dir /b "C:\MainFolder\Dir\"') DO (
  For /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('dir /b "C:\MainFolder\Dir\%%M"') DO ( 
    if "%%S"=="C.txt" ( 
      echo Found C
    ) else if "%%S"=="D.txt" ( 
      echo Found D
    ) else (
      REM Code to delete the file Or Directory
      echo Deleted %%S
    )
  )
)
echo Deleted Unwanted Content
pause
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked for me. 
Here's my Working Code: 

    @echo off
    set /p path= enter absolute/relative Path upto root Folder 
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%M in ('dir /b "%path%\"') DO (
    For /f "tokens=*" %%S in ('dir /b "%path%\%%M"') DO ( 
    if "%%S"=="web.config" ( 
    echo Found web.config
    ) else if "%%S"=="web.bak" ( 
    echo Found web.bak
    ) else (
    rmdir /s /q "%path%\%%M\%%S"
    del /f "%path%\%%M\%%S"
    echo Deleted %%S
    )

    )
    )
    echo Deleted All Unwanted Content
    pause